# Track previous value of multiple select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these three `select`'s, I want to save all previous selected options, using `each`, I've done it for one of them but is there any way to do so without using same code for each of them? using `each`, for example.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pg1L2nk/6/)

```js
$(function() {
  var previous;

  $('#dropdown1').focus(function(e) {
    previous = $(this).val();
  });

  $('#dropdown1').change(function(e) {
    alert("previous value = " + previous + ", current value = " + $(this).val());
    previous = $(this).val();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown1">
  <option>10</option>
  <option>20</option>
  <option>30</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdown2">
  <option>40</option>
  <option>50</option>
  <option>60</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdown3">
  <option>70</option>
  <option>80</option>
  <option>90</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array to maintain previous value for each select. and modify change and focus to target all select element and refer/modify their respective previous value from array:

```
var previous=[];
var selectelements = $('select');
$('select').focus(function(e){
   previous[$('select').index(this)] = $(this).val(); 
});

$('select').change(function(e){
    alert("previous value = " + previous[$('select').index(this)] + ", current value = " + $(this).val());
    previous[$('select').index(this)] = $(this).val();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a899pt2v/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` selector instead of `ID`

```js
$(function(){
    var previous;
    
    $('.ddl').focus(function(e){
       previous = $(this).val(); 
    });
    
    $('.ddl').change(function(e){
        alert("previous value = " + previous + ", current value = " + $(this).val());
        previous = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown1" class="ddl">
    <option>10</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>30</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdown2" class="ddl">
    <option>40</option>
    <option>50</option>
    <option>60</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdown3" class="ddl">
    <option>70</option>
    <option>80</option>
    <option>90</option>
</select>
```

Comment: perfect ! this one I think is better for me

Comment: @reshad: this wont refer to correct previous value for each select.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar but it seems to work fine. but could you explain why you say so, I want to see your point of view and learn

Comment: @reshad: it overwrites previous value everytime on focus. You sure you do not want them to be maintained in their respective position in array? if not then this is the solution for you

Answer (score 0):

Try using array

```
$(function() {
    var previous = [];

    $('#dropdown1').focus(function(e) {
        var data = $(this).val();
        previous.push(data);
    });
});
```

Now all of change will keep in your `previous`

Update : if you want to retrieve the last index

```
$('#dropdown1').change(function(e) {
     var last_index_value = previous[previous.lenght];
     alert("previous value = " + last_index_value + ", current value = " + $(this).val());
     previous.push($(this).val());
```

});

Comment: I don't think it would be a good idea, because then it is difficult to retrieve them.